# Как перенаправить с субдомена www на основной домен в Apache?

Tags: apache

Имеется несколько виртуальных хостов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить в неосновной хост перенаправление на основной.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.site
        RedirectMatch permanent /(.*) http://site/$1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName site
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Не забудьте добавить запись типа A в настройки домена, чтобы www.site указывал на тот же ip, что и site.